# find <Object> src or <embed> src inside <iframe> using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, object

i want to access the  and data value and embed src vlaue inside of the object tag which is inside html page inside iframe. as shown below

```html
<body>
 
<iframe id="if20" width="300" height="250">
<!DOCTYPE>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>Test</title>
        </head>
<body>
<object type="" data="" width="300" height="250" id="fw1"><param name="" value="opaque">
<param name="" value="always">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<param name="flash vars" value=">
</object> 
<object width="670" height="369">

<param name="ABC" value="always">
<param name="movie" value="">
<embed src="abc.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="670" height="369">
</object>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
</body>
```

So can i access the value of object tag??

Comment: What did **You** try ?

Comment: Dont you want to use jQuery?? Seriously ?

Comment: Is the iframe on the same domain?

Comment: i want to use javascript. and the iframe content maybe of other domain

Answer (score 0):

you can access values inside of iframe only, if you don't violate [CORS](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) rules. That means, the iframe has to be on the same domain, otherwise this won't work.

If the iframe is on the same domain, you can access it via the following line after the DOM is ready.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("if20");
```

At this point the iframe isn't ready, yet. It has to finish loading:

```
iframe.onload = function(){ /* further code goes here */ };
```

Inside the callback you can then access the elements inside the iframe like:

```
var objectEl = iframe.contentDocument.getElementById("fw1");
```

If you need the window-object of the iframe use `iframe.contentWindow`.